# how to import a custom csv in magento?

Tags: magento, csv, import, magmi

I have a magento store, I know how to export/import, but currently I use Magmi and after import I cannot see the pictures nor the categories. Does anyone have another CSV import option? Or does anyone know how to fix picture & category issue with Magmi ?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Nikos, I slightly edited your post. I hope it is ok for you. Otherwise, you might as well rollback the change. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Please post an example snippet (including the headers and a few rows) of the CSV file you are trying to import with Magmi.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to your Magmi configuration page
2. Under the `Configure Current Profile` section, make sure you enable the following plugins:

   - On the fly category creator/importer ([Documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer))
   - Image attributes processor ([Documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor))

Read the Documentation provided for these plugins for the correct formats used in your CSV.

Also ensure the rest of your configuration settings are setup correctly.  Magmi is a complex tool designed with system integrators and developers in mind.  You must read the documentation and follow the steps to ensure you have set it up for correct use.

Additionally, when asking Import related questions, it's a good idea to provide an example of the datasource (CSV) file you are working with.  This allows us to better determine where the cause of your import issues are occuring.

Comment: I sent you an email on your GMAIL ... as I cannot uploade here the CSV. Cheers Axel